# how can i send sms to all my database entries at the same time

Tags: php

I have a form for contributions and I want the savings contribution, withdrawal and total balance to be sent to each member when the submit button is clicked but each time the button is clicked the savings contribution, withdrawal and total balance is been stored in the database but the SMS is been sent to only the last member in the database. How can I make it work that each member will get his / her corresponding sms

```php
if (
                !empty($_POST['RegNumber']) && !empty($_POST['Savings']) &&
                is_array($_POST['RegNumber']) && is_array($_POST['Savings']) &&
                count($_POST['RegNumber']) === count($_POST['Savings'])
                    ) {
                $RegNumber_array = $_POST['RegNumber'];
                $savings_array = $_POST['Savings'];
                $asavings_array = $_POST['Accum_Savings'];
                $withdrawer_array = $_POST['Withdrawer'];
                $awithdrawer_array = $_POST['Accum_Withdrawer'];
                $fsavings_array = $_POST['fSavings'];
                $totalb_array = $_POST['Total_Balance'];
                $firstNamem_array = $_POST['FirstName'];
                $phone_array = $_POST['Phone'];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($RegNumber_array); $i++) {

                    $RegNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($RegNumber_array[$i]);
                    $savings = mysql_real_escape_string($savings_array[$i]);
                    $asavings = mysql_real_escape_string($asavings_array[$i]);
                    $withdrawer = mysql_real_escape_string($withdrawer_array[$i]);
                    $awithdrawer = mysql_real_escape_string($awithdrawer_array[$i]);
                    $fsavings = mysql_real_escape_string($fsavings_array[$i]);
                    $totalb = mysql_real_escape_string($totalb_array[$i]);
                    $firstNamem = mysql_real_escape_string($firstNamem_array[$i]);
                    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($phone_array[$i]);
//Query fetching user goes there.
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not complete. you are doing transaction for one particular user so that user is being sent. if you want to send all database users it can be done. but what is the total entries in database. for example if you have 100-1000 users in database that is ok to send once but if you have 10 million users and you want to send all then your server may crash if it is not properlly optimized and sending all users once is not advisable but you can run some loop for example 100 uses at a time and update in database with some idetifier that sms has been sent to these guys and start next loop from balance id.

for example

```
   select * from tableA where id > '9999' and status='0' order by id desc limit 100
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for this type of cpu intensive/background job via cron or using some parrallel execution, I would use a idepedent self built script and keep the delivery status into an idepedent table for example.

```
Table: SMS_Status
id | balance_id | delivery_status | message | usage
Foreign Keys: balance_id to balance/user table whatever
Primary Key: id
DELIVERY_STATUS: ENUM NOT_SENT, SENDING, DELIVERED
```

So In any case I want a particular user to receive an SMS I would insert an entry into this table:

```
Insert Into SMS_Status(balance_id,message,usage) VALUES (...)
```

And Before each delivery I would execute:

```
UPDATE SMS_Status SET delivery_status="SENDING" where id=^some_id^
```

And I will fetch it using pagination:

```
  SELECT balance_id,message FROM SMS_Status where delivery_status="NOT_SENT" order by balance_id desc LIMIT ^some_offset^, ^page_size^
```

For pagination look on [this](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/) and [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/pagination-of-mysql-query-results-2694115) and mysql's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)